Can GRUB2 be scaled? If so, how? If not, why not?
Rationale
The XOrg 11 and KWin Wayland compositors are able to scale their outputs using 1:1 (integer — an example is 100%) and non-integer (125%) scales. However, I see no information online about how to scale GRUB.
Instead, all I see are examples of workarounds utilizing the GRUB_GFXMODE="$RESOLUTION" variable to input a lower resolution value than its output device is capable of.
Question
Consequently, can GRUB2's output be scaled? If so, how (I presume that the relevant variable is undocumented)? If not, why not (I presume that the functionality is merely absent)?
Duplicates
I have asked for information specific to my OS/distribution (Fedora) at discussion.fedoraproject.org/t/138655. However, because reddit.com/r/EndeavourOS/comments/ysx08r hasn't yet been answered, I'm not expecting any useful responses there.
SE is my last port of call.

experiment with different font sizes

Answered here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1394984/small-font-size-console-and-grub

@ArtemS.Tashkinov, those do not answer this question, although I'm thankful for the attempted assistance. They advise that the user modify the font size and resolution, which is explicitly what I want to avoid, because although setting the font size is technically scaling, it's not a scaling of the entire GUI, and a resolution decrease renders it redundant anyway. I want to scale the entire GUI, as any decent compositor can. Otherwise, the borders shall be too small despite the font being suitable, or the text resolution shall be too slow to render some characters properly.

"modify the font size" - you've said nothing about fonts in your question. "the borders shall be too small" borders of what and why is this an issue? "or the text resolution shall be too slow to render some characters properly" - this doesn't make any sense. In the end: you've not even tried but you claim it won't work for you.

@ArtemS.Tashkinov, I meant “too low” instead of “too slow”. It was merely a failure of autocorrect. Indeed, I've not mentioned font size, because I don't want to merely scale the fonts. Instead, I want to scale the entire GRUB2 TUI. I suggest that you observe wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=GNU_GRUB&oldid=1255212178#/media/File:Debian_Unstable_GRUB2_(2015).png, which demonstrates how GRUB can have surrounding decorations (it'd be a CLI otherwise). I want those to scale too.

@ArtemS.Tashkino, my example was somewhat poor. As the photograph attached to https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?60914#comment0 demonstrates, at high enough resolutions, the TUI itself can become so small that even increasing the font size to tremendous proportions would be inadequate, because ascertaining which is selected would be difficult. That is why I want the TUI itself to scale too. Note that at such a high DPI, reducing the resolution of GRUB2 proportionately would be as problematic due to how solely Latin (and maybe Greek) could be rendered at such low resolutions.

@RokeJulianLockhart all of the graphics are text character based ... changing the font size might affect the borders also

@jsotola, I might try that then. Thanks. However, which characters do you presume it uses? Box-drawing ones?

the GRUB uses a text window, so I guess that the box-drawing character set is used ... run a test to confirm ... please post an answer if the result is a success ...https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box-drawing_characters

one of the answers has a picture ... it shows that text characters are used to form the borders ...https://askubuntu.com/questions/11846/no-box-characters-after-changing-the-default-grub-font#12050

@jsotola, I see what you mean: askubuntu.com/revisions/11852/4. This really may work. It'll take me some time, but I'll certainly provide an answer when I get around to it.
